# Why does newUser only returns an id and none of the other values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose

I'm trying to create a node.js application with authentication and I had this as my original code:

```
let newUser = new User({

    first: req.body.first,
    last: req.body.last,
    uname: req.body.uname,
    pwd: req.body.pwd

});

console.log(newUser);
```

and the `console.log(newUser)` was returning only `_id` value but not any other values.

So I tried turning all of my values into strings, like this:

```
let newUser = new User({

    first: 'req.body.first',
    last: 'req.body.last',
    uname: 'req.body.uname',
    pwd: 'req.body.pwd'

});

console.log(newUser);
```

But I was still getting only the value of an `_id` in the console

Here's what console returns `{ _id: 5d4a15eb6fa02d2954bb0826 }`

Comment: We cannot answer your question because it depends on the User class. Does User have a `valueOf` or `toString` method?

Comment: @slebetman `const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);`, do you need `UserSchema`?

Comment: Ah. You should add mongoose as a tag since it's not simply a behaviour of javascript/node.js

Comment: I don't use mongoose so I don't know but it's common for databases to return the id of the newly created object. For example postgres and sqlite

Comment: Sorry @slebetman I completely forgot to tag mongoose, and it should return the values it assigns in addition to the `_id`, at least that's how it went before...